# How to "melt" `pandas.DataFrame` objects in Python 3?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe, melt

I'm trying to `melt` certain columns of a `pd.DataFrame` while preserving columns of the other.  In this case, I want to `melt` `sine` and `cosine` columns into `values` and then which column they came from (i.e. `sine` or `cosine`) into a new columns entitled `data_type` then preserving the original `desc` column.

**How can I use `pd.melt` to achieve this without melting and concatenating each component manually?**

```
# Data
a = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
DF_data = pd.DataFrame([a, np.sin(np.pi*a), np.cos(np.pi*a)], index=["t", "sine", "cosine"], columns=["t_%d"%_ for _ in range(100)]).T
DF_data["desc"] = ["info about this" for _ in DF_data.index]
```

[image]

The round about way I did it:

```
# Melt each part
DF_melt_A = pd.DataFrame([DF_data["t"],
                          DF_data["sine"],
                          pd.Series(DF_data.shape[0]*["sine"], index=DF_data.index, name="data_type"), 
                          DF_data["desc"]]).T.reset_index()
DF_melt_A.columns = ["idx","t","values","data_type","desc"]
DF_melt_B = pd.DataFrame([DF_data["t"],
                          DF_data["cosine"],
                          pd.Series(DF_data.shape[0]*["cosine"], index=DF_data.index, name="data_type"),
                          DF_data["desc"]]).T.reset_index()
DF_melt_B.columns = ["idx","t","values","data_type","desc"]

# Merge
pd.concat([DF_melt_A, DF_melt_B], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

If I do `pd.melt(DF_data` I get a complete meltdown

[image]

In response to the comments:
[image]

Comment: did you try something like this `pd.melt(DF_data, id_vars=[('sine','cosine')], value_vars=['values'])`

Comment: Hey @StevenG thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it above but got all `np.nan` values?

Comment: what about  `pd.melt(DF_data, id_vars=['sine','cosine'], value_vars=['values']) `

Comment: It creates a column called `value` which has all `np.nan` and loses the `t` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allright so I had to create a similar df because I did not have access to your `a` variable. I change your `a` variable for a list from 0 to 99... so t will be 0 to 99

you could do this :

```
a = range(0, 100)
DF_data = pd.DataFrame([a, [np.sin(x)for x in a], [np.cos(x)for x in a]], index=["t", "sine", "cosine"], columns=["t_%d"%_ for _ in range(100)]).T
DF_data["desc"] = ["info about this" for _ in DF_data.index]

df = pd.melt(DF_data, id_vars=['t','desc'])
df.head(5)
```

this should return what you are looking for.

```
     t             desc variable     value
0  0.0  info about this     sine  0.000000
1  1.0  info about this     sine  0.841471
2  2.0  info about this     sine  0.909297
3  3.0  info about this     sine  0.141120
4  4.0  info about this     sine -0.756802
```

Comment: Ahh! Sorry about that man.  I totally forgot to add `a` on there.  It's just `a = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
`